# LWP::Simple get() fails mysteriously

Tags: perl, lwp

In http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/lwp.html the first example with LWP::Simple didn't work. I simply copied the code and ran:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $content = get('http://www.perlmeme.org') or die 'Unable to get page';
print $content; 

 exit 0;
```

And it didn't work, threw error: `Unable to get page at get.pl line 6.`

What's going on?

Comment: Works for me ... ?  This `perl -MLWP::Simple -wE'say get("http://www.perlmeme.org")'` prints the page (ran from command-line).

Comment: Thank, didnt work either, I got
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
Also tried with perl -e LWP::Simple -wE 'say get("http://www.perlmeme.org")' , no luck

Comment: Oh ... that's about basic syntax ... well,  I really meant to say that you probably have a connection issue or some such (since it works for me).

Comment: You are probably right, my firewall and proxy is filtering my script out, I will have to try at home, but its very frustrating as you probably can understand that everywhere I read they tell LWP useragent is so easy but I cant even simply get a json out. I will ask that in another post. Sorry...

Comment: eh, sorry about that ... i sure get the frustration.  This problem, it seems that it's not about the module.  That `JSON` thing ... yes, ask a question.

Comment: On Windows you need to invert the quotes: `perl -MLWP::Simple -wE "say get('http://www.perlmeme.org')"` (but that will just give you the same non-result).

Answer (score 2):

LWP::Simple really is simple. It assumes the `GET` request will probably succeed and does not provide any interesting error information.

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $agent->get('http://www.perlmeme.org');

$response->is_success or die $response->status_line;
print $response->decoded_content;
```

That should at least give you an error message.

(You don't need `exit 0` at the end; that's the default behavior anyway.)

Comment: Thanks but didnt work, i got :
500 Can't connect to www.perlmeme.org:80 at get.pl line 8.

Comment: @dbnoob Can you `ping www.perlmeme.org`? Also, what OS are you on?

Comment: No, i cannot ping, im behind proxy and firewall, but I tried out intranet website and still no luck. But I get 401 unauthorised error...may be thats why.

Comment: @dbnoob Yeah, looks like something is blocking your connection attempts. 401 means the connection succeeded, but the site itself rejected your request. It probably wants a username / password.

Comment: oh, im on windows...
thanks @melpomene, you all are very helpful, i shall try from home and post back.

Comment: Hey guys,It works from home. Thanks zdim and melpomene

Comment: I wrote [HTTP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Simple) if you want an LWP::Simple-like interface with more useful (or at least, existing) error handling.